Error when installing libheif with homebrew
when I try to upgrade libheif on MacOS 11.7.10, the following error occures:
==> Upgrading libheif
  1.16.2 -> 1.18.2
==> cmake -S . -B build -DWITH_RAV1E=OFF -DWITH_DAV1D=OFF -DWITH_SvtEnc=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH=@loader_path/../lib
Last 15 lines from /Users/heiko/Library/Logs/Homebrew/libheif/01.cmake:
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/local/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.2")
-- Checking for module 'gdk-pixbuf-2.0'
--   Found gdk-pixbuf-2.0, version 2.42.12
Package gdk-pixbuf-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gdk-pixbuf-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gdk-pixbuf-2.0' found
CMake Error at gdk-pixbuf/CMakeLists.txt:19 (install):
  install TARGETS given no LIBRARY DESTINATION for module target
  "pixbufloader-heif".

I already set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH in the .zshrc file to the path, where gdk-pixbuf-2.0 is located:
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Cellar/gdk-pixbuf/2.42.12/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0:/usr/local/Cellar/gdk-pixbuf/2.42.12/lib"

But when I run
brew upgrade libheif --verbose

It throws me:
...
==> ENV
...
PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /usr/local/opt/brotli/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/highway/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/imath/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/jpeg-turbo/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/libpng/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/xz/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/lz4/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/zstd/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/libtiff/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/little-cms2/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/openexr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/webp/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/jpeg-xl/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/libvmaf/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/aom/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/libde265/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/pcre2/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/mpdecimal/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/readline/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/python@3.12/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/glib/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/x265/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/shared-mime-info/share/pkgconfig
...

So the path to gdk-pixbuf-2.0 is not in PKG_CONFIG_PATH.
What can I do to upgrade libleif on MacOS 11.7.10?

You need to reference the pkgconfig for your gdk-pixbuf 2.42.12 installation. Ideally, this should do the job export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/gdk-pixbuf/2.42.12/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH" (note putting the config in the beginning rather in the end would avoid conflict/override)
Also 11.7.10 is not supported by Homebrew anymore, https://docs.brew.sh/Acceptable-Formulae#supported-platforms

This is a known issue and is not platform-specific.  In fact, your fellow homebrew maintainer patched the libheif formula two days ago by disabling pixbuf gdk-pixbuf support ("force off gdk-pixbuf").
FYI/TLDR;
Also, there's still a lot of us on Intel Macs who need homebrew support.  While I understand that it's not feasible for the project to support older macOS versions (10.15.7) however the community appreciates any help we can get moving forward.

A homebrew maintainer recently patched the libheif formula which disables gdk-pixbuf support. If you don't need gdk-pixbuf support for heif then consider this as a temporary fix.
